# Why is ArrayList able to remove this?

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, wrapper

In Integer Wrapper classes ,whenever we compare like this

```
Integer a=546;
Integer b=546;
System.out.println(a==b);
```

it returns false,but then why when there is a collection

```
ArrayList<Integer> a=new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(5);
a.add(546);
Integer g=546;
a.remove(g);
```

it removes it from the ArrayList??

Comment: Because `remove()` compares with `equals()`, not with `==`

Comment: From the doc of `remove(Object o)`: _"Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. [...] More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))"_ What does `a.equals(b)` prints?

Comment: You told it to be removed. What is the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `ArrayList.remove` doesn't use *reference identity* (which is what you get with `==`) - it uses `equals`.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-):

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index `i` such that `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))` (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).

And `equals` *will* return true:

```
Integer a = 546;
Integer b = 546;
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // true
```

Note that if it didn't use `equals`, it would be pretty broken for things like `String` as well:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("foo");
list.remove(new StringBuilder("f").append("oo").toString()));
System.out.println(list.size()); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the correct way to compare objects is using equals:

```
Integer a=546;
Integer b=546;
System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

And that's what is used by ArrayList.

By the way, if you create a new class, you have to write your own equals method in order to work properly.

Comment: When I started to write my answer there wasn't any other one, Skeet posted it just a minute before.

Answer (score -1):

a==b works on absolute memory locations. if a,b point to the same memory location it returns true. however remove() method works on the equals implementation. since according to equal method every Integer instance with value 546 is equal to anyother, that value is removed from list.